# Ubuntu 22.04.1 Screencast generate a corrupted video (freezed)

Tags: desktop-recording

Using the screencast provided with ubuntu (when pressing "Print screen" key) is launching correctly.
Everything seems to work fine during the record.

Anyway, the file generated is like a screenshot. It's a video with only the first frame. Mouse, window and nothing are moving. The video is just freezed.

Sometimes, it start to move, and then freeze again in the video.

I don't find any solution on internet.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to work by simply deleting `~/Videos/Screencasts`, but I've still found it to be a bit glitchy (for example in my case it won't record any windows not in frame when I start the recording, even if I bring one in frame during).

Comment: Yes, it seems that moving a new window to the frame crash everything

Comment: Do you really get [a recording icon on some top bar](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html) after clicking the round button starting the video capture? my system is an upgrade from 20.04, and it seems not to really start the video capture.